Exclude all files and directories except specifics in vscode
I want to exclude everything in the explorer window in vscode
I have looked at the following posts, but I simply can't get the syntax to work:
how-to-exclude-all-folders-except-one-folder-in-vscode
how-to-exclude-all-but-certain-files-in-the-sidebar-in-visual-studio-code
I wish to exclude everything except files ending on *_1.pdf. I have the following syntax, which doesn't work:
    "files.exclude": {
    "manuals/**/*[^_][^1][^.][^p][^d][^f]": true,   
}

I have also tried the following:
    "files.exclude": {
    "manuals/**/*": true,                            
    "manuals/**/*_1.pdf": false,                     
},

and just about a million other alterations. What am I missing?

maybe you should use "manuals/**/*_1.pdf": false, without "manuals/**/*": true,

Sticking to the syntax, this would tell VScode not to hide files ending with _1.pdf, but without hiding the other files ("manuals/**/*"´: true) it wouldn't do anything.

I don't know this function but in some tools order is important - maybe you have to set first "manuals/**/*_1.pdf": false, and later "manuals/**/*": true,

no dice, "manuals/**/*": true, hides everything.

you may have to ask authors of VS Code if it is possible, and if it is not possible then ask them to add this functionality
